# Mac Dictation - How to select backspace?

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

Using OS X 10.9 and 10.10 dictation, I can find/use the various grammatical commands [as shown here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5449?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). Is there a way to select back, erase, cancel?

When I try these words, they are typed not implemented.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution 1: You can say "Press backspace key" (at least with 10.10).

---

Solution 2: You can define the voice command "backspace" that triggers [an automator workflow that sends a delete keystroke](https://superuser.com/q/321599/116475):

```
on run {input, parameters}

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke (ASCII character 127)
end tell

return input
 end run
```

---

Solution 3: You can use [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) (free):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When I say "Press Backspace Key", the dictation system usually types "Christmas". I have to say it very slowly and deliberately, and then it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a custom Dictation Command of CTRL-H.

I'm using Mojave, but this should work for any version that has the Enhanced Dictation feature.

1. In Preferences/Accessibility/Dictation, select the Dictation Commands button
2. Under the left column click the plus (+) button
3. On the right, in "When I say:" enter the word you want to use. I used "Delete"
4. In the "Perform" dropdown menu, select "Press Keyboard Shortcut"
5. At the prompt, press Control and H. "Press ^H" should appear
6. Click Done

[image: Accessibility - Dictation Commands Menu]